# Deploy of a Web Application failed on WebLogic 12c

Tags: exception, deployment, weblogic, jax-ws, failed-installation

I have this exception when I try to deploy an application on WebLogic 12c.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getContainer(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:120)
>   at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:138)
>   at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:68) at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240) at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
>   at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256) at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)****

In this application  I have a simple jax-ws Web Service.
Can anyone help me?

Regards,
Francesco

Comment: Would need to know the classpath. Sounds like `WLSContainer`, which lives in weblogic.jar, is depending on another class that it can't find to initialize properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the JAX-WS runtime of your project. So, the application load by default the JAX-WS runtime from the server.